# Can we have a model of ZFC for any increasing cardinality function over its ranks?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, cardinal-characteristics

Per Löwenheim–Skolem theorems, is it a result that we can have a model of $\sf ZFC$ with any increasing cardinality function over its ranks?

Formally, is the following scheme consistent with $\sf ZFC$?

$ f: {\sf Ord \to Card}\\ \forall \alpha \forall \beta:  \beta \geq \alpha \to f(\beta) \geq f(\alpha)\\ \implies\\ \exists M: (M  \models {\sf ZFC}) \land \forall   \alpha \geq \omega: |V_\alpha^M| = f(\alpha) $

> if so, would the same result hold for transitive models of $\sf ZFC$?

Comment: Clearly not. If $f(\alpha+1)>2^{f(\alpha)}$, then this cannot hold.

Comment: Why? I thought the upward L-K can pump up the cardinality of the next stage to whatever we wish to

Comment: In what sense is $f$ inside $M$, then?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, $f$ is not inside $M$.

Comment: Then my first comment holds.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, is $|V^M_\alpha| \leq |V_\alpha|$?

Comment: If $M$ is not a well-founded, indeed transitive, in what sense does $\alpha$, an external ordinal corresponds to $V_\alpha^M$? If it is transitive, then $V_\alpha^M\subseteq V_\alpha$.

Comment: Nice! Well my naive attempt was for the $\alpha^M$ to be what $M$ sees as $\alpha$, in other words $\alpha^M$ is a definable ordinal in $M$ whose definition (externally) is exactly equal to the definition of $\alpha$ with relativization to $M$, so $V_\alpha^M$ is what $M$ sees as the $\alpha$ iterative stage of $\emptyset$, i.e. the definition of $V_\alpha^M$ is exactly equal to the definition of $V_\alpha$ relativized to $M$.
so if $\alpha$ is parameter free definable after $\phi$ then $\alpha^M$ is definable after $\phi^M$, i.e. the formula $\phi$ with all quantifiers bounded by $M$.